# Javascript append items to array one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add items to an array every time a button is clicked passing the string to be added, but it is replacing items rather than appending to the existing one.

here's the code:

```html
<button onClick={() => handleFilter('chairs')}>chairs</button>
<button onClick={() => handleFilter('sofas')}>sofas</button>
<button onClick={() => handleFilter('tables')}>tables</button>
```

and the function I'm calling is:

```
const handleFilter = (filterType) => {
  
  const result = [];
  result.push(...result, filterType);
    
  console.log(result);
}
```

What I want is to add to the `result` array `["chairs"]` when I click the chairs button, then `["chairs", "sofas"]` when I click the sofa button etc. But what's happening is that the items are added to the array replacing the existing one, so I'll end up always with the array containing only one element, the one I clicked. I know that this is something to do with how I reference the `result` array but can't figure it out.

example code

```js
const handleFilter = (filterType) => {

  const result = [];
  result.push(...result, filterType);

  console.log(result);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 80%; }
```

```html
<button onClick="handleFilter('chairs')">chairs</button>
<button onClick="handleFilter('sofas')">sofas</button>
<button onClick="handleFilter('tables')">tables</button>
```

Comment: `const result[];` isn't valid Javacript btw.

Comment: Are you using React? Is `result` an `useState` or something like that?

Comment: Sorry just a typo, editing it now

Comment: How about then doing exactly what the title says _"append items to array one by one"_. That's what `push` is for .. in its most simple usage ... `result.push(filterType)` ... `const result = [];` then of cause needs to be initialized outside the handler function. And one also has not yet implemented anything which protects each filter item to be present multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising new array every time you call the function you should make that variable global scope for all three functions.

```
const result = [];
const handleFilter = (filterType) => {
   result.push(filterType);
   console.log(result);
}
```